# What is the difference between HTMLDivElement and HTMLElement (except for the inheritance relationship)?

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom

I read [HTMLDivElement - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement#instance_properties) and it seems that `HTMLDivElement` introduces nothing new.

But `<div>` would be rendered as a block while the autonomous element created from `HTMLElement` would be rendered as an inline element.

Did I miss something here?

Comment: The JS DOM API does not determine how elements are rendered. Consider that web browsers existed *before* JS.

Comment: *"while the autonomous element created from HTMLElement would be rendered as an inline element"* I'm curious how you would instantiate an anonymous HTMLElement so you could see it rendered? (And why do you assume it would be inline? The default varies by element type.) Given you can only create them via `createElement` and similar, which require a tag name, and which return the appropriate sub-interface?

Comment: *"...it seems that HTMLDivElement introduces nothing new."* Well, it introduces a deprecated (obsolete) `align` property, as the MDN page you linked shows (you can also see that [in the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#HTMLDivElement-partial)).

Comment: The rules of HTML — content rules, default `display`, etc — don't have a lot to do with the DOM APIs. Once you've got a DOM, all those rules have been followed during its construction. Note also that the effect of CSS on how the DOM is rendered visibly doesn't affect the behavior of the API (except for `getComputedStyle()` of course).

Comment: Maybe I should have said "hardly affects the behavior".

Comment: More generally, a subclass doesn't have to introduce any new interfaces. Think of `HTMLElement` as an abstract base class, and `HTMLDivElement` as a concrete implementation of that class.